# Inverse function problem

Tags: functions

I have the function $$f(x)=e^{x-3}+x-e^2$$ and I have already prove that is a monotonic increasing function. But I want to solve the equation $$f^{-1}[2\cdot{ln(x)}+2]=f^{-1}[ln^2(x)-1]$$ and it is difficult to find the range of the function (because I don't know derivatives) in order to find the type $f^{-1}(x).$ So any ideas?

Comment: you can use the LambertW function to find the inverse function

Comment: I don't know this function

Comment: Hint: A function which is monotonic increasing is one-to-one.

Comment: You also don't need derivatives to compute the range.  As $x$ gets close to negative infinity, $e^{x-3}$ approaches $0$, $x$ approaches negative infinity, and $e^2$ doesn't change, so the function approaches negative infinity.  Similarly, as $x$ approaches infinity, $e^{x-3}$ approaches infinity, $x$ approaches infinity, and $e^{-2}$ doesn't change, so the function approaches infinity.  Since the function is continuous, its range is all real numbers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to compute the inverse of the function in order to answer the question (actually, the point of the question is likely to use facts about functions instead of trying to come up with a formula).

A function which is monotonic increasing is one-to-one and its inverse is also one-to-one.  In other words, if 
$$
f^{-1}(2\ln(x)+2)=f^{-1}(\ln^2(x)-1)
$$
then 
$$
2\ln(x)+2=\ln^2(x)-1.
$$
Let $y=\ln(x)$, then you must solve
$$
2y+2=y^2-1.
$$
A brief trip through the quadratic formula gives that

> $y=-1$ or $y=3$.

Then, you can exponentiate your answer to get

> $x=\frac{1}{e}$ or $x=e^3$.